# Databricks OPTIMIZE does nothing

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

I have a partitioned delta table. I noticed that some partitions contains huge amount of tiny data files.

[image]

Here a comparison between two partitions with very similar data.

[image]

I now did run:

```scala
Running OPTIMIZE:
OPTIMIZE delta.`dbfs:/mnt/backup/bronze/DeviceData`
WHERE Partition_Date = '2023-01-19'
+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|path                              |metrics                                                                                                                                                     |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|dbfs:/mnt/backup/bronze/DeviceData|{0, 0, {NULL, NULL, 0.0, 0, 0}, {NULL, NULL, 0.0, 0, 0}, 1, NULL, 0, 63, 63, true, 0, 0, 1705194826563, 1705194828732, 8, 0, NULL, {0, 0}, 7, 7, 0, 0, NULL}|
+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and after it:

```scala
Running VACUUM:
VACUUM delta.`dbfs:/mnt/backup/bronze/DeviceData` RETAIN 0 HOURS
Deleted 0 files and directories in a total of 653 directories.
+----------------------------------+
|path                              |
+----------------------------------+
|dbfs:/mnt/backup/bronze/DeviceData|
+----------------------------------+
```

As you can see already in the logs, it does absolute nothing related to bin-packing.
I have the same amount of tiny files and no optimization.

I'm using the last databricks runtime: 14.2 (includes Apache Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.12).

What I'm doing wrong?

--- UPDATE 1 ------------------------

@rainingdistros

No, when I order the files of this partition by timestamp, there was nothing written since the data was created in the first place. In other partitions the optimization worked (see second screenshot).

[image]

--- UPDATE 2 ------------------------

Base on some old databricks community post I tried now to rerunn the command with `spark.databricks.delta.optimize.preserveInsertionOrder` deactivated and also printing out the result.

```json
{
    "numFilesAdded": 70,
    "numFilesRemoved": 4381,
    "filesAdded": {
        "min": 16899041,
        "max": 613054015,
        "avg": 303944954.8857143,
        "totalFiles": 70,
        "totalSize": 21276146842
    },
    "filesRemoved": {
        "min": 159655,
        "max": 9243024,
        "avg": 4173938.1842045197,
        "totalFiles": 4381,
        "totalSize": 18286023185
    },
    "partitionsOptimized": 1,
    "zOrderStats": {
        "strategyName": "minCubeSize(107374182400)",
        "inputCubeFiles": {
            "num": 0,
            "size": 0
        },
        "inputOtherFiles": {
            "num": 4381,
            "size": 18286023185
        },
        "inputNumCubes": 0,
        "mergedFiles": {
            "num": 4381,
            "size": 18286023185
        },
        "numOutputCubes": 1,
        "mergedNumCubes": null
    },
    "numBatches": 1,
    "totalConsideredFiles": 4381,
    "totalFilesSkipped": 0,
    "preserveInsertionOrder": false,
    "numFilesSkippedToReduceWriteAmplification": 0,
    "numBytesSkippedToReduceWriteAmplification": 0,
    "startTimeMs": 1705705885113,
    "endTimeMs": 1705710361132,
    "totalClusterParallelism": 4,
    "totalScheduledTasks": 1,
    "autoCompactParallelismStats": null,
    "deletionVectorStats": {
        "numDeletionVectorsRemoved": 0,
        "numDeletionVectorRowsRemoved": 0
    },
    "numTableColumns": 7,
    "numTableColumnsWithStats": 7,
    "totalTaskExecutionTimeMs": 8150342
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's already optimal?

Comment: But how could it with all that small file. It impacts the performance of this partition. In other partition I have 4-5 ~450MB, instead it 2,000 < 5MB files

Comment: Upon running OPTIMIZE, do you see visually files with bigger/smaller sized being written to the ADLS storage path ?

Comment: @rainingdistros I answered in the main question

Comment: I understand that you have just provided code as example, but for confirmation, you are running the OPTIMIZE command with filter of 20-Feb right ? Truth be told, I am not aware of the internal workings. I could think of a couple of options...One option would be that the files are already in optimal condition. Alternatively based on your need try adding a Z-Order on your most used columns and check if that helps in any way. Or consider Liquid clustering. Note: Pls evaluate if it fits your requirement before trying it out. Sorry if it is not relevant or helpful...

Comment: Yes, I was running it with `WHERE Partition_Date = '2023-01-20'`. I did it because I discover that optimizing the complete table keep partitions like this in a extreme fragmented state. Also performance wise it's in a very bad state because queries have to target thousands of tiny files, when hitting this partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option solved the problem:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.optimize.preserveInsertionOrder", false)
```

The Spark configuration option `spark.databricks.delta.optimize.preserveInsertionOrder` is specific to Delta Lake on Databricks. This option controls how the `OPTIMIZE` command orders the data in a Delta table when it compacts small files into larger ones.

Here's a brief explanation of what this option does:

- **Preserving Insertion Order (`true`)**:

  - When this option is set to `true`, the `OPTIMIZE` command preserves the original insertion order of the data in the table. This means that during file compaction, data is organized in the same order as it was originally written.
  - Preserving the insertion order can be important for certain use cases where the sequence of data is relevant. For example, if you're dealing with time-series data, keeping records in the order they were inserted might be beneficial for certain types of queries or for understanding the dataset's evolution over time.
- **Not Preserving Insertion Order (`false`)**:

  - When this option is set to `false`, the `OPTIMIZE` command does not preserve the insertion order. Instead, it might reorder data based on other considerations, such as optimizing for query performance. For example, it may sort data based on certain columns if `ZORDER BY` is used in the `OPTIMIZE` command.
  - Not preserving the insertion order is typically more efficient in terms of query performance, especially for large datasets, since the `OPTIMIZE` command can organize data in a way that is more optimal for read access patterns.